# Kafka with avro records

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, apache-kafka, flume, avro

I have the following:
Source - kafka topic (trans)
Channel - memory
Sink - Hdfs (avro_event)

The data in the kafka topic trans has been written using a c# producer and has thousands of avro records. When I run my flume consumer, it starts to sink the data to the hdfs. The problem is that the data is in the format: schema 
data 
schema 
data

instead of:

schema
data
data

I am guessing this is because flume is expecting  a record type with {header} {body}  whereas the data coming from kafka will just be {body}
I know there is a way you can wrap the avro data been written to the topic in an avroFlumeEvent but then it seems that it is no longer a true avro record and maybe a spark consumer or storm will prefer the data in true avro down the line. Is there a way to process this topic so the data is written without multiple schemas everytime flume rolls the data to hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

We actually got this working in the end. We were using the microsoft .NET avro library instead of the apache avro library in the C# producer. This meant the avro record was serialized correctly. I also needed to change the flume sink to use "org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.AvroEventSerializer$Builder" as the sink serializer instead of "avro_event". I also needed to include a flume interceptor connected to the kafka source which pushes the variable "flume.avro.schema.url" into the flume header to be later used by the hdfs sink serializer.

I had a look at camus but it seemed overkill for what we were trying to implement, a basic flume channel connected to a kafka topic which sinks the avro data to the hdfs.

I just ripped the interceptor bit from my java app that builds the flume config in the hopes that it might help others who encounter this problem:

```
                _flumeFileConfigProperties.put(_agentId+".sources." + _sourceId +".interceptors",_interceptorId);           
                _flumeFileConfigProperties.put(_agentId+".sources." + _sourceId + ".interceptors." + _interceptorId + ".type","static");
                _flumeFileConfigProperties.put(_agentId+".sources." + _sourceId + ".interceptors." + _interceptorId + ".key","flume.avro.schema.url");
                _flumeFileConfigProperties.put(_agentId+".sources." + _sourceId + ".interceptors." + _interceptorId + ".value",_avroProdSchemaLocation +_databaseName + "/" + _topic + "/record/" + _schemaVersion + "/" + _topicName + ".avsc");
```

Comment: Hi @Colman I am stucked in same issue even after using interceptor do you still have solution file for your code

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using Camus from LinkedIn, once you land the data on kafka. It will run mapreduce job but you should get the desired schema data data layout. You should also look at Confluent's kafka stack especially the schema registry it provides and the rest api it provides.